# Trying to skip implicit parameter list

Tags: scala, implicit

I'd like to call a function returned by a function with an implicit parameter, simply and elegantly. This doesn't work:

```
def resolveA(implicit a: A): String => String = { prefix =>
  s"$prefix a=$a"
}

case class A(n: Int)
implicit val a = A(1)

println(resolveA("-->"))  // won't compile
```

I've figured out what's going on: Scala sees the `("-->")` and thinks it's an attempt to explicitly fill in the implicit parameter list. I want to pass that as the `prefix` argument, but Scala sees it as the `a` argument.

I've tried some alternatives, like putting an empty parameter list `()` before the implicit one, but so far I've always been stopped by the fact that Scala thinks the argument to the returned function is an attempt to fill in the implicit parameter list of `resolveA`.

What's a nice way to do what I'm trying to do here, even if it's not as nice as the syntax I tried above?

Comment: @som-snytt, the `implicitly` in your deleted answer was helpful for my real code! I've already found a case where it solves the problem well.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use the `apply` method of the `String => String` function returned by `resolveA`. This way the compiler won't confuse the parameter lists, and is a little shorter than writing `implicltly[A]`.

```
scala> resolveA[A].apply("-->")
res3: String = --> a=A(1)
```

Comment: Mmm, yes! This is much nicer than the solution I've been using so far, which is to spell out the implicit arguments explicitly. BTW, I just noticed that I don't need the `[A]` type parameter; I'll remove it from the question now. (The real code that this is a huge simplification of has type parameters all over the place.)